# How to clean this Helmet?

Tags: cleaning, helmets

[image]

My son has that helmet for bicycles. Its brand new and was gifted to him recently. Unfortunately due to my mistake it was left in the backseat of our car and has accumulated some dust/lint which is making it look dirty.

I want to clean it but don't know how, I don't wish to ruin it by just trying with a wet cloth. Its surface texture is like a very high quality tennis ball and it's not the carbon fiber hard top ones that I'm used to.

Any help would be great, That helmet is beautiful and I don't want to ruin it in haste.

Comment: A damp (not wet) cloth is the usual way of removing lint. A lint roller might also work.

Comment: Mild scrubbing with a damp rag will not hurt it.  After all, the thing must be able to survive in the rain.

Comment: Is this a real helmet?  I've not seen cloth ones since the 80s - all modern helmets have hard plastic outer shells.  To be fuzzy like a tennis ball would stop it sliding easily and it would dig in causing twist damage to the wearer?

Comment: @DanielRHicks that's the first level for cleaning tennis balls too.  Second is to add some hand soap and warm water.   Other tennis ball options like "add to washing machine" are probably a bad idea though :)

Comment: OK I'm confused.  Google suggests that Atlas make Motorbike helmets and armor, but not bicycle helmets.   There is a brand called Giro that have a model called Atlas, but its a regular looking helmet.   "KOVFS 1992:2" is a Swedish standard for helmets.   So I googled the phone number which lead me to a closed website of http://www.atlasbike.com/     **UPSHOT** I think this helmet is at least a decade old, and of a style that provides less crash protection than modern helmets.  I'd replace it with a modern lid.  (comment cos not an answer)

Comment: Criggie that’s what I thought. I have never seen ones like that. We will clean it up and keep it on the shelf I guess

Comment: @Criggie good spot -- helmets have come on a lot since 1992 when that standard waas presumably written.

Comment: Google translation of http://www.sportatlas.se/en/company/ indicates that Bil AB Atlas was sold to MECA in 2004. This helmet is probably 15+ years old.

Comment: WRT "KOVFS 1992:2". It may be possible to cross-check the age by checking if/when the next revision of the standard came into force. The idea is that if a new standard came into force in, say, 1998, then the helmet is definitely older than 1998. Obviously, if the new standard was only published in 2017 the helmet could still be from before 1998. Etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd run it under a cold shower if the lint roller suggested in the comments (or not too sticky tape) didn't work. A helmet that can't take a cold shower can't take rain and is therefore useless unless you live in a desert (which Sweden, where it apparently comes from, isn't renowned for).

One further thing to try is a vacuum cleaner with a soft brush attachment. Ideally you'd use reduced power or open a vent hole so you don't suck too hard.